# Problem when creating package for exporting SQL Server table to excel with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm fairly new to SSIS, so please have some patience :)

I'm trying to export a table or stored procedure (in this case a table since it's easier) to excel but I'm getting error when executing the package, the server is a SQL Server and I'm connecting using the OLE DB Source.

This is the error I'm getting:

> SSIS package "C:\xxx\Integration Services Project3\Package.dtsx" starting.
>
> Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
>   Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
>   Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
>   Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
>
> **Error: 0xC0202009** at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
>
> An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80040E21
>   Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "worker_reference" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "placement_reference" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "worker_name" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "job_title" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "authorising_line_manager" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "company_agent_name" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "type_of_worker" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "hours_worked" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "rate_description" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "rate_per_hour" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "job" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "work_stage" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "project_name" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "location" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
>
> Error: 0xC0202025 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcvWn.png): Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.
>
> Error: 0xC004701A at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Excel Destination 1 failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202025.
>
> Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
>   Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: "Excel Destination 1" wrote 0 rows.
>   Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
>
> Task failed: Data Flow Task 1
>   Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (17) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
>
> SSIS package "xxx\Integration Services Project3\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
>   The program '[6128] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I'm not sure if may have anything to do with the connection or the columns I'm creating in Excel, the workbook has the same columns as the database table.

Maybe what I'm doing wrong is the mapping, I've tried with a data conversion in the middle, but I keep getting otherwise the error "cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode.."

### I'm adding bit more info regarding configurations:

[image]

### This is the default configuration the data convert has:

[image]

### This is the default mapping in the excel output:

[image]

And changing all the data convert data types from **text stream [DT_TEXT]** to **Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]** is what allows me to be able to run it and gives me the error shown above

Comment: Is a CSV (vs excel) file acceptable?

Comment: not really, because I actually need the excel file to be password encrypted (haven't figured out that part yet) but for it to be password protected it has to be xls as far as I know

Comment: OK, just be aware that a password encrypted file is no more secure than a password encrypted ZIP file containing a CSV.

Comment: and it is possible to output a .zip file encrypted? I mean, I'm not sure if it's out of the question, but I need it to have some type of encryption, at the same time, I'm not able still to process the package with what I have, is there maybe more information I could provide to help with it?

Comment: It's possible to encrypt any file but that's another story. With regards to your original problem, I would have to dive in and fiddle around to work it out but perhaps you could try recreating your target excel file with friendlier data types. DT_TEXT is not friendly. DT_STR (or DT_WSTR) is "friendlier". When creating your package there should be a step where it creates the excel file with defined data types.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, the friendlier data types, I'll work on that... also, I never had a step in package creation for creating the excel file, I created it manually on my own. maybe you're onto something here.. I'll also investigate on that now

Comment: You've got data types in your SQL database. Those are explicitly defined. You've got data types in Excel and these unfortunately are usually wrong / unexpected and cause big problems. If you let SSIS create the excel file, I think you can specify the data types manually.... I think from memory. I always avoid importing and exporting data with Excel because it's a very unreliable and temperamental data storage format. If your objective is to create a datafile for data transfer then you should use TAB delimited instead.

Comment: If you use Excel as a a data transfer format, they will have the same set of issues importing an excel file on the other side. With regards to protection, there are any number of ways to secure a file. Encryption and password protection are two different levels of data security. Password protection on excel or Zip stops the "honest" hacker. It can be broken. Encryption is the "proper" way to protect files but it depends how far you want to go.

Comment: for what I understand the password protection is just to comply with politics, the file is actually secure and just need to "have password protection" in regards of the excel file, we need it to be like that as not so tech savvy persons receive it and we need them to have consistency in what they get. being a report they can consume easily and that they can receive over e-mail periodically, hence the excel export to later be send via e-mail (I believe this can also be done with SSIS)

Comment: OK so it's security theatre - that's fine. The real point here is this is a report that "users can consume easily". Which _usually_ means Excel is the only option. So you do need to solve the Excel option.